# FaunaDB get document stored with foreign key

Tags: database, facebook-fql, faunadb

I've created two tables in FaunaDB, "customers" and "orders". I created an Index, to get a document by a `data.transactionObj.transactionId`.

So far so good, but how can I extend the query below, to get the document referenced in `data.customerRef`?

This query:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Match(Index("orders_by_trx"), "220704142800610948")),
  Lambda("x", Get(Var("x")))
)
```

returns

```
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("orders"), "336256180042072264"),
      ts: 1660641327310000,
      data: {
        customerRef: Ref(Collection("customers"), "340132521031237836"),
        transactionObj: {
          transactionId: "220704142200610948",
          status: "transmitted",
          refno: "l56pwwmiHuber",
          currency: "CHF",
          paymentMethod: "TWI",
          amount: 100
        },
        cart: {
          cards: [
            {
              id: "629f6e2f909b7c89f114a874",
              name: "MCA Couchtisch Sakura",
              verkaufspreis: 99,
              anzahl: 1,
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compose the response as an arbitrary JSON value.

You haven't specified what structure you need, so I'm assuming that you want something like:

```
{
  order: <order document>,
  customer: <customer document>,
}
```

To accomplish that, here's an updated query that should work:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Match(Index("orders_by_trx"), "220704142800610948")),
  Lambda(
    "order_ref",
    Let(
      {
        order: Get(Var("order_ref")),
        customer_ref: Select(["data", "customerRef"], Var("order")),
        customer: Get(Var("customer_ref")),
      },
      {
        order: Var("order"),
        customer: Var("customer")
      }
    )
  )
)
```

The query used the `Let` function to hold intermediate results and compose the response structure.

Fauna queries can perform any number of reads and writes provided that you don't exceed the [transaction limits](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/learn/understanding/limits).

Comment: That does it indeed, thank you so much! I must say, I find FQL not easy to grasp and beside your official documentation there is not much else to be found in the web about it to guide newbies.

About your solution: The first object in `Let` is the input where I declare variables, and the second argument is the output, in this case an object?

Since you referred to the transaction-limits, how could I improve that query to receive a single document instead of an array? I think this one loops over all documents in a collection?

Comment: Your query uses `Map` to iterate over all of the documents that match the transaction id. If you know that there is only one such document, such as by using an index where `unique` is true, then you can `Select(["data", 0], Map(...))` to pull out the first result.